# Django testing, can't see anything in test database

Tags: mysql, django, automated-tests

I am running some tests in Django using

```
from django.test import TestCase
```

and subclassing that.

My tests run, but when I step through them in debug mode, I want to check what is happening in MySQL. But I can't see anything in MySQL. (I am using a settings file that points to a local instance of MySQL for the tests).

Logging into MySQL via the command line, or Pycharm I can see that 
he test_database gets created correctly (and torn down after the test have run. But when I query any tables they via the mysql client, they are empty. I can use the ORM to do CRUD operations on the database and they behave as expected (viewing the objects in PyCharms debugger).

Why can't I see any data in MySQL? 
Are the tests wrapped in some transaction so that a different login won't see those changes? Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: When using `django.test.TestCase` -- Each test is run inside of a transaction to help provide isolation between tests. According to the docs, you can use `unittest.TestCase` to avoid this overhead, at the cost of possibly losing isolation.

Comment: Thanks, I had a feeling it was something like that.